# OrientDB Lightweight Edges with Ridbags?

Tags: orientdb, orientdb-2.1

Recently I've come across a use case where it made a lot of sense to use lightweight edges. It made for much faster queries when checking whether two vertices are related as part of the select conditional.

That said, because I operate in a highly concurrent environment, I've run into some conflicts (OConcurrentModificationException). I got past this by setting the conflict strategy to auto-merge for that particular class.

In investigating further, I came across this article on concurrency when adding edges: http://orientdb.com/docs/2.1/Concurrency.html#concurrency-when-adding-edges

It recommends using RID Bags for situations where edges change very frequently, and has the neat advantage of not incrementing the version each time an edge is added/removed. Sounds great, but I can't get it to work.

I've tried adding the -DridBag.embeddedToSbtreeBonsaiThreshold=-1 to my client, with no effect. I then went into my code and added:

OGlobalConfiguration.RID_BAG_EMBEDDED_TO_SBTREEBONSAI_THRESHOLD.setValue(-1);

I finally also tried adding the -DridBag.embeddedToSbtreeBonsaiThreshold=-1 to my orientdb server (in server.sh).Still no effect. Each time the edges get updated, the version gets incremented (which is how I assume I can tell that its not working properly).

Does anybody have thoughts about how lightweight edges might work with ridbags (or not work for that matter)?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you running distributed?

Comment: No I'm not, I know there are restrictions in that context.